# Null Values in a CASE statement

Tags: t-sql, insert, case, checksum

I am playing around with some stuff in SSMS to learn a little more as I study for my 70-461 exam and I came across a little hangup. I am trying to create a table to play around with so I don't have to alter/delete any of the already created tables in the AdventureWorks or TSQL2012 databases. I've created a temp table to test my code before I actually create a table to play with and this is the code I am using to insert values into my table:

```
DECLARE @i INT = 1
 WHILE @i < 10
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #TestEmployeeCountry 
    VALUES ( SUBSTRING('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP', @i, 1), 
        CASE (SELECT ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%10 +1)
            WHEN 1 THEN 'USA'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'CANADA'
            WHEN 3 THEN 'MEXICO'
            WHEN 4 THEN 'UK'
            WHEN 5 THEN 'FRANCE'
            WHEN 6 THEN 'SPAIN'
            WHEN 7 THEN 'RUSSIA'
            WHEN 8 THEN 'CHINA'
            WHEN 9 THEN 'JAPAN'
            WHEN 10 THEN 'INDIA'
        END)
    SET @i = @i + 1
    END;
```

The problem I am having is I keep getting an error saying "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Country', table 'tempdb.dbo.#TestEmployeeCountry" The reason this is is because I have the Country column set to NOT NULL, and my code does work for some of the inserts, the problem is I randomly get NULL values out of my case statement.

I know that to fix this I can easily add another line that says "DEFAULT xxxxxx" however I want to understand what is going on because based on what I see I shouldn't have to do that, should I? I thought I wrote my case statement correctly, giving me a number between 1-10 only and upon testing just that specific select statement over 1000 tries, I always get a random number between 1-10, nothing larger or smaller. Can anyone help me to understand why this code tries to enter a NULL value into that column?

Answer (score 8):

Why this happens has already been answered by @PaulWhite in the SO question: **[How does this CASE expression reach the ELSE clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21918536/how-does-this-case-expression-reach-the-else-clause/21918828#21918828)**

To solve it, you should calculate the `ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%10 +1` outside/before the `INSERT` statement so it is calculated once. Something like:

```
DECLARE @i INT = 1 ;
DECLARE @rand INT ;
 WHILE @i <= 10
   BEGIN
    SET @rand = ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%10 +1 ;
    INSERT INTO TestEmployeeCountry 
    VALUES ( SUBSTRING('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP', @i, 1), 
        CASE @rand
            WHEN 1 THEN 'USA'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'CANADA'
            WHEN 3 THEN 'MEXICO'
            WHEN 4 THEN 'UK'
            WHEN 5 THEN 'FRANCE'
            WHEN 6 THEN 'SPAIN'
            WHEN 7 THEN 'RUSSIA'
            WHEN 8 THEN 'CHINA'
            WHEN 9 THEN 'JAPAN'
            WHEN 10 THEN 'INDIA'
        END) ;
    SET @i = @i + 1 ;
   END ;
```

Also notice that with your code, the 10 countries will **not** be placed in the table with equal probability! The first country (`USA`) will have 10% chance, the second will have 9% ( `(100%-10%)*10%` ), the third 8.1%, (`(100%-19%)*10%`), etc. That leaves a not so small chance (around `1/e`) that none of the 10 is chosen and the `CASE` expression goes to the default `ELSE NULL` and you get the error. (You can check the probabilities if you allow nulls in the column and run the **[SQLfiddle script](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/df6c8/14)**.)

According to the above, another way to solve it would be to change the expressions to comply with how SQL-Server executes the `CASE` and all 10 cases have the same probability:

```
    CASE 0
        WHEN ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%10 THEN 'USA'
        WHEN ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%9 THEN 'CANADA'
        WHEN ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%8 THEN 'MEXICO'
        WHEN ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%7 THEN 'UK'
        WHEN ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%6 THEN 'FRANCE'
        WHEN ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%5 THEN 'SPAIN'
        WHEN ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%4 THEN 'RUSSIA'
        WHEN ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%3 THEN 'CHINA'
        WHEN ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%2 THEN 'JAPAN'
        ELSE 'INDIA'
    END
```